# Using ActionFilterAttribute for model validation

Tags: c#, validation, enterprise-library

I am trying to use ActionFilterAttribute to validate the model when a call is made to my Web API. I have added the following

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   {
       if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
       HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added standard validators to my model properties and it all works fine. However when I add a custom class level validator it fails with the following error.

> A validation attribute of type XXXValidatorAttribute cannot be used to
>   validate values."
>
> StackTrace: at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.BaseValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)\r\n   at
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.Validators.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, Object container)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ShallowValidate(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container,
>   IEnumerable'1 validators)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container,
>   IEnumerable'1 validators)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object
>   model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
>   HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter'1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

This validator works fine when I invoke it via a unit test using a validation factory. I am not sure why it fails during ModelState validation? What is the difference between the two?

I have the model defined as

I have a model defined as

```
[CashDetailValidator()]
public sealed class CashDetails : DetailsBase
{
    // Reference Number
    [ValidatorComposition(CompositionType.Or)]
    [NotNullValidator(Negated=true)]
    [StringLengthValidator(1, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 16, RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, MessageTemplate = "Reference number should be between 1 to 16 characters in length.")]
    public string RelatedReference { get; set; } ...........................
```

}}

The composition validator also gives the same error.

Comment: Could you submit where you add this attribute? and when this error happen?

Comment: I edited the initial question with the attribute location. The error occurs when the http post request is made and the validation filter kicks in.

Comment: Where are you using `ValidateModelStateAttribute` then? and also please post your action too.